# Access: GROUP BY with IIf() condition

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to run the following Code in Access:

```
SELECT T_SAP_IST.month, SUM(T_SAP_IST.value), IIf([description]="hours","hours","nonhours") AS descr
FROM T_SAP_IST
GROUP BY month, descr
```

My goal is to get the sum of all values for every month divided into "hours" and "nonhours". However, I get an error which says "'IIf([description]="hours","hours","nonhours")' is not part of an aggregate function"

How can I fix this? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MS Access, you need to repeat the expression:

```
SELECT T_SAP_IST.month, SUM(T_SAP_IST.value), 
       IIf([description]="hours","hours","nonhours") AS descr
FROM T_SAP_IST
GROUP BY month, IIf([description] = "hours", "hours", "nonhours");
```

You can also use a subquery, so you don't have to repeat the expression.  MS Access does not support column aliases in the `GROUP BY`.